# Php problem reading mysql data and comeparing it to output

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables in my database `users` and `trade`.

`trade` has two key columns:

```
trade_id 
user_id
trade_name
```

`users` has one key column:

```
user_id
username
```

I want to list the usernames and trade_names of the that share the same id;

```
    if(isset($_POST['button'])){
      require 'datamanagement/connect.php';
      $sqlU="SELECT * FROM users;";
      $sqlT="SELECT * FROM trade;";
      $resultU=mysqli_query($conn,$sqlU);
      $resultT=mysqli_query($conn,$sqlT);
        while($users=mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultU)){
          while ($trades=mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultT)) {
            if($trades['user_id']==$users['user_id']) {
              echo "<div> username ".$users['username']."  ".$trades['trade_name']." </div>";
            }
            $trades=mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultT);
          }
      }
    }

?>
```

Comment: Look up the sql JOIN syntax and use that

Comment: It is also useful to see a example of the result you want

Comment: ___PS___ You dont want the line `$trades=mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultT);` inside a while loop that is already processing that data or you will find you are missing every other row in your results